# Two disjoint intervals minimum sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, intervals

Given a list of N intervals [a,b] cost c, find the minimum sum of 2 non-overlapping intervals. I have an algorithm in O(n^2) (  pastebin.com/kveAZTwv ) but i don t find the O(N log N).

The first value is the number of intervals. the other lines are : a,b,c where a is the beginning of the interval, b the end and c the cost.

example :

```
input :
3
0 10 1
1 2 2
9 12 2



output :
4
```

Comment: Please show your O(n^2) solution. It's easier to come up with an improvement of an existing algorithm than to write one from scratch.

Comment: What do these input values represent?  Why is the output 4?

Comment: here is my O(n^2) :https://pastebin.com/kveAZTwv

Comment: The first value is the number of intervals. the other lines are : a,b,c where a is the beginning of the interval, b the end and c the cost.

Comment: @Jones, edit your original post instead of adding comments, align code accordingly. You may benefit from this documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic idea for an algorithm in O(n log n), I am sure it can be done more efficiently:

1) sort all intervals accoring to their endpoint, each endpoint is a potential splitpoint where intervals to the right and intervals to the left do not overlap

2) now scan through the sorted intervals and for each spiltpoint remember the minimum cost interval to the left.

3) sort all elements according to their startpoint

4) for each splitpoint memorize additionally the minimum cost interval to the right(having its startpoint after the splitpoint). This is also possible with a single scan from back to front of the sorted elements

5) for each splitpoint add the two corresponding cost and look for the minimum.

Sorry this is a bit informal since i am on mobile.

Comment: We can wait until you reach your PC, there is no rush to post it on mobile